# Git Checkout - npm run watch - nothing changed

Tags: git, branch, commit, git-branch

I've been working on a branch on a particular project for the past month and haven't performed any sort of merges to my master.

Today, I went on to check some of the changes on my websites behaviour by comparing the master to my branch.

So I checked out to master, ran npm run development and visited the website. However, I was still seeing everything I had implemented on my branch. Nothing changed between moving branches, which doesn't make sense. All the features I've implemented on my branch are active on master when I've never merged these together.

It's not the first time this has happened before, it seems as if there's some sort of cache meddling here that I can't get rid of.

How can I sort this?

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

There's a scenario where problem mentioned by you may occur.

It is possible that earlier, your branch and master were in sync [history of both the branches was exactly identical] and in the past month, you made changes to your branch and did NOT commit those.

If you check out master now, those uncommitted changes will be visible in master as well since history of these branches was same. Hence, when you run npm run dev, essentially same code is getting built again and therefore you would have seen the same output on master as well.

To avoid this, you can commit your changes to your local branch and then switch to master. Now, master branch will not have the latest commit unless you merge your local branch to master. And you will be able to see the difference in the output.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. There's nothing to commit currently on either branch. Everything's been committed, but it still doesn't perform the changes when moving branches.

Comment: Then, there are few more checks to be performed:
1) is the top commit of your branch present in master ? If yes, then your branch is a subset of master and two will show same output.
2) If no, try deleting then dist/output folder when you switch to every branch and then run npm run dev. It will create fresh set of binaries every time and you can be certain that there are no stale changes.

Comment: 1. No. Top commit on my branch is not on master.
2. Where shall I find that folder?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: It'll be right under your project directory. Depends on what configuration you use in your bundler (like webpack). Naming it as dist is common convention.

Comment: Do you mean delete the webpack.mix.js.dist?